# No module named 'ImageTk'

Tags: python, tkinter

I am learning tkinter and trying to place an image on a Button, but I cannot get past the import.

My code:

```
from tkinter import *
from PIL import Image, ImageTk
```

The error:

```
No module named 'ImageTk'
```

Based on a post I saw when researching this I tried 
      sudo apt-get install python-imaging-tk

which says I already have the latest version.

I am on a Raspberry Pi3, with a new install of Raspbian and I did an upgrade and update to be sure.

Any suggestions?

Here is the output of `apt-cache show python-pil` requested in a comment below:

```
Package: python-pil
Source: pillow
Version: 2.6.1-2+deb8u3
Architecture: armhf
Maintainer: Matthias Klose <doko@debian.org>
Installed-Size: 1050
Depends: python (<< 2.8), python (>= 2.7~), python:any (>= 2.7.5-5~), mime-support | python-pil.imagetk, libc6 (>= 2.11), libfreetype6 (>= 2.2.1), libjpeg62-turbo (>= 1.3.1), liblcms2-2 (>= 2.2+git20110628), libtiff5 (>= 4.0.3), libwebp5, libwebpdemux1, libwebpmux1, zlib1g (>= 1:1.1.4)
Suggests: python-pil-doc, python-pil-dbg
Breaks: python-imaging (<< 1.1.7+2.0.0-1.1)
Replaces: python-imaging (<< 1.1.7+2.0.0-1.1)
Provides: python-pillow, python2.7-pil
Multi-Arch: same
Homepage: http://python-pillow.github.io/
Priority: optional
Section: python
Filename: pool/main/p/pillow/python-pil_2.6.1-2+deb8u3_armhf.deb
Size: 277856
SHA256: 9f4e54fbe21fde51c13f4c875a09045a05a61abb55db723c4b09c14ce125eb4d
SHA1: 1e0369561c91e3d8fcaced1027f281ffc05fda32
MD5sum: ec0be47a97ef8aea42211eb1c19ce6bf
Description: Python Imaging Library (Pillow fork)
 The Python Imaging Library (PIL) adds an image object to your Python
 interpreter. You can load images from a variety of file formats, and
 apply a rich set of image operations to them.
 .
 Image Objects:
  o Bilevel, greyscale, palette, true colour (RGB), true colour with
    transparency (RGBA).
  o colour separation (CMYK).
  o Copy, cut, paste operations.
  o Flip, transpose, resize, rotate, and arbitrary affine transforms.
  o Transparency operations.
  o Channel and point operations.
  o Colour transforms, including matrix operations.
  o Image enhancement, including convolution filters.
 .
 File Formats:
  o Full (Open/Load/Save): BMP, EPS (with ghostscript), GIF, IM, JPEG,
    MSP, PDF, PNG, PPM, TIFF, XBM.
  o Read only (Open/Load): ARG, CUR, DCX, FLI, FPX, GBR, GD, ICO, IMT, IPTC,
    MCIDAS, MPEG, PhotoCD, PCX, PIXAR, PSD, TGA, SGI, SUN, TGA, WMF, XPM.
  o Save only: PDF, EPS (without ghostscript).
Description-md5: 7fb415befc961c94ce8c999eb6902e95
```

Comment: What version of P{ython are you using?

Comment: Have you tried this import ImageTk

Comment: After installing this sudo apt-get install  python-pil python-imaging python-imaging-tk
 the above import statement works in 2.7.9. Note: the above command does not require from Pil

Answer (score 5):

I've just checked on my own pi and installing python-pillow does not install the extra libraries that I believe are needed (same goes for python-pil if you are using that one).

I think you need to install both: **python-imaging** and **python-imaging-tk** as suggested here: http://effbot.org/imagingbook/imagetk.htm

Comment: Thanks - still not working.  I went into terminal and did sudo apt-get install python-imaging which did install some new code, but I still get the same error when I try my code.  So it appears that ImageTk is no longer in PIL????

Comment: That is interesting it worked for me. Did you also install the python-imaging-tk module?. I'm using python 2.7.9 and pillow rather than pil.

Comment: Yes I did.  It reports python-imaging-tk is already the newest version.  How can I see what is in that module (sorry - Linus newbie)

Comment: I'm at a loss I'm afraid.  Can you run: `apt-cache show python-pil`  from the terminal and copy in the output please. The only thing that come to mind is you might be installing it for Python 2 and trying to import it into Python 3.  Can you run `python --version` as well.

Comment: Thanks for your help.  Seems I am running python 2.7.9 although I don't know why.  Here is the info you requested:

Comment: Python 2.7.9 is what I would expect so you're ok there and it's the same as the version I have and you seem to have access to the same version of python-pill as I do (I was worried mine was an older version).  Can you try Steve Robillards suggestion in his comments to your question?

Comment: Thx. I tried Steve Robillars suggestion and each command said I was up to date.  If I take out From PIL in the import statement I get No Module Named Image.  If I leave in From PIL I get No Module Named ImageTk.  Very strange.

Comment: open the python terminal by typing python at the command line. Then type help('modules') you should see ImageTk in the list if not you missed one of the install commands. If it is there type the following: import ImageTk if you don't get an error the module has loaded correctly.

Comment: try the imports like this from tkinter import * then from PIL import Image then import ImageTk

Comment: I've decided to reinstall the operating system and start over.  I found similar problems reported on other powsts and forums and no solutions.  Thanks  to those of you who tried to help.

Answer (score 2):

I am currently using the raspberry pi and I realized that the latest version of python that it uses is python 3 or 3.5, so if you don't download ImageTk for python 3 or higher, it will not work. you can do this by using this code:

```
sudo apt-get install python3-pil.imagetk
```

Answer (score 0):

I did this:

```
sudo apt-get install python-imaging python-imaging-tk
```

and got:

```
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
Note, selecting 'python-pil.imagetk' instead of 'python-imaging-tk'
```

and it installed the new library and it worked for me.

Comment: .. and 'python-imaging' no longer exists, although 'python-imaging-doc-html' and 'python-imaging-doc-pdf' do